# Solve N systems of equations without using a loop

Tags: matlab, octave

I have `N` systems of linear equations with `k` variables each. I have to solve all of them but without using a loop. I know that in order to solve a system of equations in matlab/octave you can do

```
x = A \ y;
```

so what I'm trying to do is to build the `A` matrix so that it consists of N blocks along the diagonal, something like this:

```
a1 b1 0  0  ...
a2 b2 0  0  ...
0  0  a3 b3 ...
0  0  a4 b4 ...
0  0  0  0  ...
     ...
```

but I just can't figure out how to do this (without a loop). Maybe there's a completely different approach available here?

I have `a` and `b` values stored in vectors.

Comment: You can use `blkdiag` to put things along the diagonal like that, but more importantly, why are you trying to put `b` in your `A` matrix? Maybe provide us an [mcve] of the equations that you are trying to solve simultaneously.

Comment: @Suever oh, the b from `x = A \ b` isn't the same as the one in the matrix, sorry for the confusion (edited my question). I know there's `blkdiag`, but I don't know how to use it without a loop - I'd have to be able to somehow build those blocks of `[a(i), a(i+1); b(i), b(i+1)]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your `A` matrix by using `blkdiag`. To construct each of the items to put along the diagonal you can use concatenation (`cat`) combined with `mat2cell` and then `{:}` indexing to pass each cell array element to `blkdiag` as a separate value.

```
a = [1 2 3 4];
b = [5 6 7 8];

% The size of each "block"
sz = 2;

inputs = mat2cell(cat(2, a(:), b(:)), repmat(sz, [numel(a)/sz, 1]));

%   [2x2 double]
%   [2x2 double]

A = blkdiag(inputs{:});

%   1     5     0     0
%   2     6     0     0
%   0     0     3     7
%   0     0     4     8
```

**Explanation**

Given `a` and `b`, we want to take every two elements of each and combine them into a matrix. The first step is that we are going to concatenate `a` and `b` along the second dimension

```
C = cat(2, a(:), b(:))

%    1     5
%    2     6
%    3     7
%    4     8
```

We want now want to break this up into 2 x 2 matrices such that the first two rows are part of one matrix, the next two are part of another matrix and so-on. We can use `mat2cell` to convert this matrix into a cell array where each element contains a 2 x 2 matrix like we described above.

The `repmat(2, [numel(a) / 2, 1])` simply says that we want an array of all 2's where the sum is equal to the total number of elements in `a` (in the answer I have replaced 2's with a generic `sz` variable). This instructs `mat2cell` how many rows to put in each cell element.

```
D = mat2cell(C, repmat(2, [numel(a) / 2, 1]))

%   D{1} =
%
%     1     5
%     2     6
%
%   D{2} =
%
%     3     7
%     4     8
```

We can then pass these cell array elements as separate input arguments to `blkdiag` using `{:}` indexing which yields a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)

```
blkdiag(D{:})

%   1     5     0     0
%   2     6     0     0
%   0     0     3     7
%   0     0     4     8
```

Comment: thanks, it's exactly what I was looking for. Could you please explain a little more how it works though?

Comment: @Dunno I have updated with a more detailed explanation of what's happening